# filter rows by a function over values of each row, data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Switch from data.frame syntax to data.table syntax is still not smooth for me. I thought the following thing should be trivial, but no. What I am doing wrong here:

```
> DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
> DT
   x y v
1: a 1 1
2: a 3 2
3: a 6 3
4: b 1 4
5: b 3 5
6: b 6 6
7: c 1 7
8: c 3 8
9: c 6 9
```

I want something like this:

```
cols = c("y", "v") # a vector of column names or indexes
DT[rowSums(cols) > 5] # Take only rows where
# values at colums y and v satisfy a condition. 'rowSums' here is just an
# example it can be any function that return TRUE or FALSE when applied 
# to values of the row.
```

This work, but what if I want to provide dynamic column names? and my tables have many columns?

```
>DT[eval( quote(y + v > 5))] #and the following command gives the same result
> DT[y + v > 5]
   x y v
1: a 6 3
2: b 3 5
3: b 6 6
4: c 1 7
5: c 3 8
6: c 6 9
> DT[lapply(.SD, sum) > 5, .SDcols = 2:3] # Want the same result as above
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: x,y,v
> DT[lapply(.SD, sum) > 5, ,.SDcols = 2:3]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: x,y,v
> DT[lapply(.SD, sum) > 5, , .SDcols = c("y", "v")]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: x,y,v
```

**Update after the answers**
Since it turns out there are many ways of doing this thing, I want to see which want is the best performer. Following is the simulated timing code:

```
nr = 1e7
DT = data.table(x=sample(c("a","b","c"),nr, replace= T),
                y=sample(2:5, nr, replace = T), v=sample(1:9, nr, T))
threshold = 5
cols = c("y", "v")
col.ids = 2:3
filter.methods = 'DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD[, cols, with = F]) > threshold]]
DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD[, col.ids, with = F]) > threshold]]
DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD) > threshold, .SDcols = cols]]
DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD) > threshold, .SDcols = c("y", "v")]]
DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD) > threshold, .SDcols = col.ids]]
DT[ ,.SD[rowSums(.SD[, col.ids, with = F]) > threshold]]
DT[ ,.SD[rowSums(.SD[, cols, with = F]) > threshold]]
DT[, .SD[rowSums(.SD) > threshold], .SDcols = cols, by = x]
DT[, .SD[rowSums(.SD) > threshold], .SDcols = col.ids, by = x]
DT[, .SD[rowSums(.SD) > threshold], .SDcols = c("y", "v"), by = x]
DT[Reduce(`+`,eval(cols))>threshold]
DT[Reduce(`+`, mget(cols)) > threshold]
'
fm <- strsplit(filter.methods, "\n")
fm <- unlist(fm)
timing = data.frame()
rn = NULL
for (e in sample(fm, length(fm))) { 
  # Seen some weird pattern with first item in 'fm', so scramble it
  rn <- c(rn, e)
  if (e == "DT[Reduce(`+`,eval(cols))>threshold]") {
    cols = quote(list(y, v))
  } else {
    cols = c("y", "v")
  }
  tm <- system.time(eval(parse(text = e)))
  timing <- rbind(timing, 
                  data.frame(
                    as.list(tm[c("user.self", "sys.self", "elapsed")])
                    )
                  )
}
rownames(timing) <- rn
timing[order(timing$elapsed),]

### OUTPUT ####
#                                                                     user.self sys.self elapsed
# DT[Reduce(`+`,eval(cols))>threshold]                                   0.416    0.168   0.581
# DT[Reduce(`+`, mget(cols)) > threshold]                                0.412    0.172   0.582
# DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD) > threshold, .SDcols = cols]]                     0.572    0.316   0.889
# DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD) > threshold, .SDcols = col.ids]]                  0.568    0.320   0.889
# DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD) > threshold, .SDcols = c("y", "v")]]              0.576    0.316   0.890
# DT[ ,.SD[rowSums(.SD[, col.ids, with = F]) > threshold]]               0.648    0.404   1.052
# DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD[, cols, with = F]) > threshold]]                   0.688    0.368   1.052
# DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD[, col.ids, with = F]) > threshold]]                0.612    0.440   1.053
# DT[ ,.SD[rowSums(.SD[, cols, with = F]) > threshold]]                  0.692    0.368   1.058
# DT[, .SD[rowSums(.SD) > threshold], .SDcols = c("y", "v"), by = x]     0.800    0.448   1.248
# DT[, .SD[rowSums(.SD) > threshold], .SDcols = col.ids, by = x]         0.836    0.412   1.248
# DT[, .SD[rowSums(.SD) > threshold], .SDcols = cols, by = x]            0.836    0.416   1.249
```

**So the Champion in term of speed is:**

```
DT[Reduce(`+`,eval(cols))>threshold]
DT[Reduce(`+`, mget(cols)) > threshold]
```

I prefer the one my `mget`. And I think the reason that other are slower because they call `rowSums`, whereas `Reduce` only helps to form the expression. Sincere thanks to all that have given the answers. It's hard to decide for me to pick the 'accept' answer. `Reduce`-based is very specific to this `sum` operation, while `rowSums`-based is an example of using arbitrary function.

Comment: that last sentence is confusing - `Reduce` is the general method, not `rowSums`

Answer (score 9):

```
cols = c("y", "v")
```

Try

```
DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD[, ..cols]) > 5]]
```

Or

```
DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD[, 2:3]) > 5]]
```

Or

```
DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD) > 5, .SDcols = cols]]
```

Or

```
DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD) > 5, .SDcols = c("y", "v")]]
```

Or

```
DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD) > 5, .SDcols = 2:3]]
```

Or

```
DT[ ,.SD[rowSums(.SD[, 2:3]) > 5]]
```

Or

```
DT[ ,.SD[rowSums(.SD[, ..cols]) > 5]]
```

Or

```
DT[, .SD[rowSums(.SD) > 5], .SDcols = cols, by = x]
```

Or

```
DT[, .SD[rowSums(.SD) > 5], .SDcols = 2:3, by = x]
```

Or

```
DT[, .SD[rowSums(.SD) > 5], .SDcols = c("y", "v"), by = x]
```

Each will result in

```
#    x y v
# 1: a 6 3
# 2: b 3 5
# 3: b 6 6
# 4: c 1 7
# 5: c 3 8
# 6: c 6 9
```

Some explanations:

1. `.SD` is also a `data.table` object which can operate within `DT` scope; `..cols` looks in the calling frames above the `[]` where it's used for the `cols` object to select columns. Thus,
   this line `DT[ ,rowSums(.SD[, ..cols]) > 5]` will return a logical vector indicating in which cases `DT` has `y + v > 5`. So we will add another `DT` in order to select this indices within `DT`
2. When you use `.SDcols`, it will narrow `.SD` only to these columns. Thus if you only do something like `DT[, .SD[rowSums(.SD) > 5], .SDcols = 2:3]`, you will lose the `x` column, thus the `by = x` was added.
3. Another option when using `.SDcols` is to return a logical vector and then imbed it in another `DT`

Comment: I'd go with `DT[DT[, rowSums(.SD) > 5, .SDcols = cols]]`.

Comment: +1 Beautiful! @Arun: Would you prefer the double join here, or the single one that I posted below!

Answer (score 6):

Here is another possibility:

```
cols <- quote(list(y, v))
DT[Reduce(`+`,eval(cols))>5]
```

Or if you'd rather keep the `cols` as a character vector:

```
cols <- c('y', 'v')
DT[Reduce(`+`, mget(cols)) > 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be:

```
cols <- quote(list(y, v))
DT[DT[,Reduce(`+`,eval(cols))>5]]
#    x y v
# 1: a 6 3
# 2: b 3 5
# 3: b 6 6
# 4: c 1 7
# 5: c 3 8
# 6: c 6 9
```