# remove rows that sum zero based on one column as key

Tags: r, sum, data.table

My goal is to remove rows that column-sum is zero excluding one specific column. Here in example, I'd like to remove based on `id` column.

```
sample_DT<- data.table(id = paste("GENE",1:10,sep="_"), laptop=c(1,2,3,0,5),desktop=c(2,1,4,0,3)) ##create data.table with three columns and 10 rows.
```

`GENE_4` and `GENE_9` need to be removed based on the data table and info in it as they have zero sum (adding laptop and desktop).

I then perform a messy piping using dplyr to get count per row and add that sum in a new column. But before that I remove the `id` column

```
perGene_summed_sample<-sample_DT %>% select(-c("id")) %>% dplyr::mutate(allele_count = rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE))
```

I then store index of rows where allele_count value is zero

```
throw_genes<- which(perGene_summed_sample$allele_count == 0)
```

Later, I again add the id column and so and so forth where the value hasn't been thrown by checking indices.

This looks so bad. Is there a better way?

Edits: removing columns names with `sample` as that is not the actual test case. I had put sample in rush to create the data.table data.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262940/filter-rows-by-a-function-over-values-of-each-row-data-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing rows where all columns except one are zeros is straight-forward:

```r
sample_DT[ rowSums(sample_DT[,-1]) > 0, ]
#         id sample1 sample2
# 1:  GENE_1       1       2
# 2:  GENE_2       2       1
# 3:  GENE_3       3       4
# 4:  GENE_5       5       3
# 5:  GENE_6       1       2
# 6:  GENE_7       2       1
# 7:  GENE_8       3       4
# 8: GENE_10       5       3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Reduce` to create a logical vector to be used in the `i`.  We specify the `.SDcols` as the columns that starts with 'sample' in column names (`patterns`- takes a regex).  Loop over the `.SD`, check if it is equal to 0 (`==`), Reduce the `list` to a single logical vector with `&`, negate (`!`) and use that to subset

```
library(data.table)
sample_DT[sample_DT[, !Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, `==`, 0)), 
      .SDcols = patterns('^sample')]]
```

If it is based on index, it can be specified as either negative or positive numeric index

```
sample_DT[sample_DT[, !Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, `==`, 0)), .SDcols = -1]]
```

If it is any `+` that equals 0

```
sample_DT[sample_DT[, Reduce(`+`, .SD) != 0, .SDcols = -1]]
```

---

Or another option is `rowSums`

```
sample_DT[sample_DT[, rowSums(.SD == 0) < ncol(.SD),
        .SDcols = patterns('^sample')]]
#        id sample1 sample2
#1:  GENE_1       1       2
#2:  GENE_2       2       1
#3:  GENE_3       3       4
#4:  GENE_5       5       3
#5:  GENE_6       1       2
#6:  GENE_7       2       1
#7:  GENE_8       3       4
#8: GENE_10       5       3
```

NOTE: Both are data.table methods and it can be extended

---

With `dplyr`, it can be done in a compact way

```
library(dplyr)# 1.0.0
sample_DT %>% 
       filter(across(starts_with('sample'), ~ . != 0))
#        id sample1 sample2
#1:  GENE_1       1       2
#2:  GENE_2       2       1
#3:  GENE_3       3       4
#4:  GENE_5       5       3
#5:  GENE_6       1       2
#6:  GENE_7       2       1
#7:  GENE_8       3       4
#8: GENE_10       5       3
```

Or using index

```
sample_DT %>% 
       filter(across(-1, ~ . != 0))
```

Comment: sorry, I'll edit column names and remove `sample`. I put there for example. The column names can follow any nomenclature.

Comment: sorry for the poor test set. column names may not follow `sample`. I've edited my post for better understanding. Thank you again :)

Comment: @DeathMetal When you say remove rows that sum 0, did you meant `-2 + 2` and remove it?

Comment: -2 +2 isn't possible in my test data. Either a person has a count for gene or not. If person has, it can be 1, 2, 3 but no count can be negative within a gene for an individual. .  :)

Comment: @DeathMetal okay, then it is fine.  I was just trying to understand the literal meaning of your title